# Meaning of potentiometer torque measurements

Tags: potentiometer

I've got a Chinese pot datasheet, and the rotational torque is listed as "20~200gf.cm".

[This Bourns datasheet](http://www.bourns.com/data/global/pdfs/PDB182-GTRB.pdf) lists

> Rotational Torque ............. 10 to 150 gf-cm

Why such a wide range?  Is this a tolerance issue, or is it something like the difference between slip and stick friction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The tolerance stackup for the torque is probably quite large, including bearing friction (2+), wiper friction, and misalignment, all of which will drift and change with age, (cycle) life, and temperature.

Comment: Then why even bother specifying it? :/

Comment: So that someone has an idea of the different torque that will be required over a lifetime without having to run their own tests.

Comment: Or why not specify each individual factor separately?

Comment: They do not probably have factors down that reliably, there is a large cost to thorough characterization. It is relatively affordable to characterize it.

Comment: Where the friction comes from shouldn't be a concern of anyone that uses it (designers or end users), and businesses aren't in the habit of disclosing anything they don't need to.  If you really need to know, you can contact their engineering department.

Comment: not to over simplify things here, but in my mind the difference between 10 and 150gf-cm is likely not detectable to a human, at least over the life span on the product.  Therefore the point of the datasheet is "its really easy to turn" and will remain so over the life of the product.  Which is really the only reason to look at this value.

Comment: We want one that's *not* as easy to turn, but the one we're replacing is "20~100", and the one we like is "20~200".  Seems kind of meaningless.

Comment: Pot torque can change noticeably over temperature.  (I think that spec is the manufacturer's way of saying "we don't care about torque that much."  In many datasheets, unflattering information ends up as a number rather than called out explicitly in the text.)

Comment: I don't know about rotary pots, but some slide pots I've seen use an oil/grease between the wiper and housing to provide a very smooth feel.  There, the friction force (fluid shear?) isn't linear, and the thixotropic properties probably change drastically even from 10°C to 30°C.

Answer (score 1):

Nick has it pretty much dead on. Whenever modeling a Sensor, motor etc you will find that you end up with a very broad range that often makes it difficult to fine tune things. Adding to what Nick said there is also the difference between static and dynamic friction the means you will have different frictions and oppoing forces depending on how the arm i moving or if it is stopped. The best solution is to design it for the worst problem X 2 then your covered.